# How can I make a function that prints something only if it's called directly?

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function (similar to `ggplot` or `lm`) that prints a value - other than what's being returned - only if it's not called by other functions (except `print`).

What I've tried:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  print(0)
  invisible(x + 1)
}
my_fun(1)         #> 0    works as desired
print(my_fun(1))  #> 0 2  should print only 0 
val <- my_fun(1)  #> 0    shouldn't print anything
```

Comment: The only way for your second example `print(my_fun(1))` to _not_ show `2` is if it chooses to return nothing, but then it'll print `NULL`. The explicit use of `print` _outside_ of your function call cannot be changed/subverted/avoided _inside_ the function call.

Comment: And in your third example, `my_fun` is not being called by another function, it is being assigned. I don't know that your `my_fun` can know if it is being assigned outside of its call. Is there a reason you're trying to give a function significantly more SA to the calling environment? I think Marcus' answer suggesting an S3 `print` method is the closest you're going to get to customizing how things are rendered on the console, but I don't know that you'll find a perfect match for your conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Marcus's answer solves the problem and digging deeper would be surplus indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably multiple ways to achieve this, but essentially you need to define a custom print method for the output of `my_fun`. In `gglot2` the function returns a data structure but the print method for that data structure is what actually renders it visually.

Here's an example of using an S3 class

```r
my_fun <- function(x){
  invisible(structure(x + 1, class = "myClass"))
}

print.myClass <- function(x, ...) {
  print(0)
}

my_fun(1)         
print(my_fun(1)) 
#> [1] 0
val <- my_fun(1)
```